# How to force the installation of a modified .bin file?

Tags: installation, binary, checksums

I modified a .bin file for the software ELAN so the path to one of my libraries is correct (after installation, ELAN can't find the library because the path is not right). So I used Emacs to correct this.

But when I use the commands to install the .bin file:

```
sudo chmod +x ELAN_440_linux_novm_install.bin
./ELAN_440_linux_novm_install.bin
```

I get the error message:

```
Preparing to install...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
The size of the extracted files to be installed are corrupted.  Please try to download the installer again and make sure that you download using 'binary' mode.  
Please do not attempt to install this currently downloaded copy.
```

This is probably because I added a few characters to the problematic string.

Is there a way to force the installation, as I know that the file wasn't corrupted before I edited it?

Comment: Modification of the install file corrupted its checksum. Wouldn't you consider to fix the PATH issue differently, e.g. using symlinks?

Comment: What are symlinks?
I have to replace the string
> nptl="`strings /lib/libc.so.6 | grep -i nptl`"
by
> nptl="`strings /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep -i nptl`"
I guess there is no way moving libc.so.6 is a good idea...

Comment: see my answer below. Just thinking: Could it be your elan stuff is 32bit, while your Ubuntu installation is 64bit? If so, and you are running into additional problems with libraries not being found, you should rather consider installing the compatibility layer *before* doing the symlink stuff below. Make sure you've got `ia32-libs` installed in the first place then - and only do the symlink if the file is not already there. Point is: 32bit apps cannot use 64bit libs directly, and vice versa.

Comment: The software is made for 32 bits, and I am using 32 bits, so it's all good. I'll try the answer, cheers!

Comment: OK, then it's fine. Just wanted to make sure we avoid additional trouble ;) So go on with my answer. I did that a lot of times successfully, so I'm pretty sure it will work out for you (using the unaltered installation package, of course ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating installation files is a bad idea in most cases like this. As you already noticed, this broke the checksum (maintained to ensure noone tampered with it and possibly introduced malicious code). A much better idea is to solve such issues outside, either by adjusting path variables (which would not work in this case), or by the use of [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink).

In your case, the solution is as easy as

```
ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

So when looking for `/lib/libc.so.6`, the binary finds the symlink and "gets redirected" to `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` (to put it into easy words -- how it works exactly, you can read in the linked Wikipedia page; but for your understanding it suffices to think of it as a special kind of "bookmark" -- so even if the file itself gets replaced, the symlink stays valid, pointing to the updated file then).

Comment: So, after running this command, does the symlink stay? Or do I have to create it every time I want to use the program?

Comment: Great, this worked, I don't get the error message any more. Cheers!

Comment: Glad that it worked out -- but to be honest, I didn't expect anything else ;) The symlink stays until you remove it again. Think of it as a "virtual file" or, if you are a programmer, a "pointer".